# Is possible in Dojo to overload constructors with dojo.declare?

Tags: dojo

Is posible in Dojo to overload constructors with dojo.declare ?

Comment: Damir, you may consider reading up on the docs a bit and experimenting instead of posting every issue you run into as you learn Dojo. You need to provide a bit more information about what you are trying to accomplish and invest a bit more into this question.

Comment: Not just this question. Every question.

Comment: If I ask a question, I try to make it a point to invest more time in the answer than I would expect ANYONE to spend writing it. It's just good courtesy to show that you aren't a freeloader off of the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/D9hc2/7/) Docs:[Dojo declare](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/declare)